# EINVAL Error in Lyx

Tags: errors, lyx, miktex, unicode

When I am typing text in the Lyx main editor window the following message keeps appearing in the Progress/Debug Message pane:

```
Error returned from iconv_open
EINVAL The conversion from UCS-4LE to UTF8 is not supported by the implementation.
```

The message also appears a bunch of times when I first open a file in Lyx.

I tried going into MikTex options and refreshing FNDB, and updating formats. I also couldn't find any packages related to iconv. In Lyx I also tried going to Tools-->Reconfigure. None of these methods has fixed my issue. This issues also happens on two different computers (both Windows PCs). I am running the newest version of Lyx (as of today), which is 2.1.4.

Comment: Do you still see this with the latest version of LyX? (2.2.3)